# Using AI to predict parameter in a function

Tags: artificial-intelligence, curve-fitting

Say, I got a dataset of intensity for each wavelength from these curves in the picture and performed curve fitting with the gaussian function for each curve to extract its parameters like peak amplitude, center, and FWHM.
[image])

I want to apply the AI method to predict the Imax (maximum Intensity), center, and FWHM for another curve in different temperatures. Say I want to predict Imax, center, and FWHM at 1 Celcius, is it possible to do so? which method should I try and how should I format the input feature and its labels? thank you.

Comment: This is certainly possible as a linear regression. I would assume you give 2 features: The temperature in Celsius, and the wavelength (nm). Then as the label, have the intensity. Train a model that learns the fluorescence intensity given the two features. Then-in order to obtain Imax, center, and FWHM-have the model predict the feature range of 1 degree celcius and 300-600 nm wavelength. The model will give back the same curve as in the graph from which you can obtain your characteristics.

Comment: suppose I have 1000 data points, does that mean I need to make it into a label array with the shape of (<num of data>, 1000)?

Comment: (1000, <features>) would be the way to go.

Comment: @neuops, thank you for your answer, please correct me if I am wrong.

I think you were a little confused between what I meant by data points and the number of curves. what I meant by data points is the number of measured intensities in a specific range of wavelength (0 ~ 600). That's why if I assume the first dimension in your answer is the number of curves, and the second dimension, the <feature>, is the number of intensities which are 1000, then everything will be pretty clear. 
Sorry for my bad English.